# Last Stone Weight Problem in Haskell using list `insert`

Tags: programming-challenge, haskell, interview-questions

## Background

Saw this problem on [TheJobOverflow](https://www.thejoboverflow.com/p/p2042/) which seems to be a [LeetCode](https://leetcode.com/problems/last-stone-weight/description/) question.

It bothered me that the "challenge" of this problem was to recognize the need for a specific data-type (in this case a `MaxHeap`/`PriorityQueue`).

> I did another, [more complicated solution](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/291327/281875), that uses folding

## Problem

> You are given a list of stones' weights (positive integer numbers);
> While there are at least two stones in the list, take the two **heaviest** stones and smash them together;

> > if the weights were equal, both stones are destroyed;
> > otherwise the lighter stone gets destroyed and the heavier one becomes the difference of the two values.
> > You know need to consider this "remainder" stone as well as all the other stones

> The process ends when there is one or no stones in the list, and the result is either the last remaining stone, or zero if there are no stones left.

### Notes

The main problem that you need to solve for here is the fact that, at all times, you need perfect knowledge/information on the state of the list. You need to know EXACTLY which two stones are CURRENTLY the two heaviest. WHILE adding to the list of known stones.

As you smash stones you will inevitably be left with a remainder stone that you need to put somewhere. The new stone might now be the heaviest or the lightest, you don't know yet and you now need to keep track of it.

> The Reference Solution (written in CPP) uses a `MaxHeap`/`PriorityQueue` as it is the most efficient way to keep the maximum sized stone (integer) in a convenient position while being able to add to the structure in efficient time.

## Personal Goals

- Attempt to not use special data types outside of base lib.
  (There is a Heap package on [Hackage](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/heap/docs/Data-Heap.html), but can we do it without it?)
- Attempt Idiomatic Haskell
  (nothing too fancy)
- Attempt a "naive" approach
  (could a beginner stumble upon this with a rudimentary grasp of Haskell?)
- Should be performant
  (probably won't be better than the cpp implementation but should be about as fast and show the same time complexity

## The Code

```hs
naiveLastStone :: (Num a, Ord a) => [a] -> a
naiveLastStone = proccess . revSort
  where
    revCompare = flip compare
    revSort    = sortBy revCompare
    revInsert  = insertBy revCompare

    proccess []  = 0
    proccess [x] = x
    proccess (x:y:ls)
      | n == 0     = proccess ls
      | otherwise  = proccess $ revInsert n ls
      where n = x - y
```

## Explanation

### Init

```hs
naiveLastStone :: (Num a, Ord a) => [a] -> a
naiveLastStone = proccess . revSort
```

compose the `process` with the `reverse sort`
we process the list in order, heaviest to smallest

### Helpers

```hs
    revCompare = flip compare
    revSort    = sortBy revCompare
    revInsert  = insertBy revCompare
```

idiomatic acceding `sort` and `insert`

### process

first the base cases: empty list means return 0 and one stone left means return it.

```hs
    proccess []  = 0
    proccess [x] = x
```

then the actual processing of the list

```hs
      | n == 0     = proccess ls
      | otherwise  = proccess $ revInsert n ls
      where n = x - y
```

1. We are operating on the presumption that the `list` is ordered, large to small. The first 2 items will be the largest, and the second largest. (we need to keep the list sorted as we work with it)
2. If `remainder` is 0, the rocks were destroyed and we process the next rocks | *else*
3. The `remainder` rock exists, we now need to put it into the the list in the correct position.
   We use [`insert`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Data-List.html#v:insert) (using our acceding `revInsert`) as it has the property
   of keeping a sorted list, sorted. Our list is now in the correct order for the next iteration.

## Performance

Checked against [TheJobOverflow](https://www.thejoboverflow.com/p/p2042/) cpp solution

| code | time | array size |
| --- | --- | --- |
| cpp (-O3) | ~0.8s | 10 000 000 |
| cpp (-O3) | ~2.5s | 20 000 000 |
| cpp (-O3) | ~3.8s | 40 000 000 |
| cpp (-O3) | ~8.0s | 80 000 000 |
| cpp (-O3) | ~10.0s | 100 000 000 |
| cpp (-O3) | ~30.0s | 800 000 000 |
| haskell (-O2) | ~0.5s | 10000 |
| haskell (-O2) | ~2.5 | 20000 |
| haskell (-O2) | ~11.3s | 40000 |
| haskell (-O2) | ~60.3s | 80000 |

Sadly my solution is showing O(n^2) as apposed to the O(n log n) of the cpp solution.

## Personal Goals Met

1. Yes
2. Yes
3. Yes
4. No^2

Comment: I'm not sure if your solution is correct. Consider for example `process 0 [10,9,8,3,2] == 4` but it should be `[10-9,8,3,2] -> [8-3,2,1] -> [5-2,1] -> [3-1] -> 2`.

Comment: You are 100% correct. I will edit

Comment: I am actually gutted right now. I got too excited about this "simple" solution and didn't properly test it. So I broke rule one for CodeReview: "don't post broken code". I am going to update it with a very much worse solution and make the post beter later. I just need it to not be wrong right now.

Comment: @maxtaldykin Does the code work now?

Comment: @pacmaninbw, Haven't tried it, but looks like it does.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Could you please [edit] to add a short summary of the problem statement?  You can keep the link as a reference, but your question does need to be complete even if the linked material isn't accessible.  Thanks.

Comment: Sorry @TobySpeight I should have chimed in. The code should be valid now after my Mar 21 Edit.
My initial code was wrong, but this (the best of my knowledge) is a valid implementation of the Last Stone Problem written in Haskell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Our first question should be *"why is it O(N^2)?"*

The `sort` seems to be a merge-sort; I trust that it's O(n log(n)).
But [`insert`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.19.1.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:insert) is noted as O(N), and you're calling it O(N) times, so it's a good bet that this is the/a problem.

I don't actually have a good solution for you. In order to have an O(log(N)) `insert`, you'll need *at minimum* an O(1)-indexing data structure, preferably an always-sorted array or maybe a tree. I can't find any such thing in base.

My only suggestion might be to unpack [the source code for `sort`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.19.1.0/docs/src/Data.OldList.html#sortBy) to somehow perform the rock-smashing during merging? Could be tricky...

Comment: Yeah thanks! I am still working the problem in my off time (my mind won't let it go). The "unpacking the merge sort" could be a very good idea! The reason it is O^2 (or might just look like it) could be that the haskell code Is, in fact, unpacking the insert, but what ends up happening is that a "tower" of thunks build up at the horizon of the list. Every subsequent iteration require (n) times of shifting the entire "tower" a step. I am testing worst case [1..n], the sort needs to flip this AND the insert needs to traverse THE ENTIRE LIST eventually to place all the 1s at the end.